# what is the meaning of settings_fields()

Tags: functions, forms, options

Please guys , I tried a lot ro find out what's the main purpose of this function , but i didn't find what i want , i looked in the codex but seriously the description is not clear , i tried to see examples but finnally i saw an example i didn't understand nothing from it .

```
<?php
echo '<form method="post" action="options.php">';
settings_fields( 'my-plugin-settings-group' );
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Via the [Developer Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/settings_fields/) (not [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/settings_fields))

> Output nonce, action, and option_page fields for a settings page.

Here's the source code for it

```
function settings_fields($option_group) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='option_page' value='" . esc_attr($option_group) . "' />";
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />';
    wp_nonce_field("$option_group-options");
}
```

so, it gives the form processor some info to work with for the current options page, and verification with [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) on submit.

### UPDATE

It's role is made more clear in the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) docs:

> To display the hidden fields and handle security of your options form, the Settings API provides the settings_fields() function. 
>   settings_fields( $option_group );

Comment: Yes Man , I Read The Developer reference For it , But it gives no Description for it , is it has a relation With The nonces ?

Comment: The code that you gave me Above Output In the console ?

Comment: So Man Every Time i Make a Form In Dashboard , I should Put It also In The code With The Options Page .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "above output in the console". `settings_fields()` is not to be used with every form in admin - it is yes, to be used in conjunction with just the options page. A read of the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) ) might provide the info you're after, they break down the logic flow of the Option pages and the role `settings_fields()`.

Comment: Thanks Man , i appreciate that , i'll give a depth read to the settings API . thanks again